# How to validate using TOM.NET if a Component is present in a specific parent Publication

Tags: web8.5, tom.net

I'm using SDL Web 8.5
While rendering a Component Presentation from child Publication, I need to validate the presence of the Component in it's top Parent Publication. It might happen that it's been created in level 2 parent Publication and localized in child or locally created in child Publication.

I do not receive a NULL object while creating a Component object with parent publication which does not exist but receive exception while accessing it's properties at runtime.

```
var ParentObject = this.Engine.GetObject<Component>(new TcmUri(repositoryChildObject.Id.ItemId,
repositoryChildObject.Id.ItemType, this.ParentPublication.Id.ItemId));
```

The globalObject is not NULL although such a Component does not exist in parent Publication.
`globalObject.Title` throws an error

> Component does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IsExistingObject to verify if the object exists, this google search shows some examples of using it: https://www.google.com/search?q=session+isexistingobject+tridion

Something along these lines:

```
if(this.Engine.GetSession().IsExistingObject(tcmUri)) { // object exists}
```

You'd need to make sure the Tcm Uri to the object you're checking is changed to reflect the actual publication.

Comment: Thanks Nuno! It works. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need, if indeed to check whether an item exists, then it's Nuno's answer. Otherwise...

> I need to validate the presence of the Component in it's top Parent
> Publication

You have a property on a Component (and other Repository Objects) which will give you the Item in the context of what you call the "top Parent Publication", see: `RepositoryLocalObject.PrimaryBluePrintParentItem`.

PrimaryBluePrintParentItem will always give you the Item from the Publication where it's created no matter how many layers it's localized in between your context Publication and  it's origin.

Comment: RepositoryLocalObject.PrimaryBluePrintParentItem.ContextRepository does not work for me when the content is localized in immediate parent publication.